What is this first item in the github steps context object with a randomly(?) generated value?
I'm having trouble finding this in the docs: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/writing-workflows/choosing-what-your-workflow-does/accessing-contextual-information-about-workflow-runs#steps-context
When I dump the steps context:
- id: test
  name: test
  env:
    GH_STEPS: ${{ toJson(steps) }}
  run: echo $GH_STEPS

I see output like this:
GH_STEPS: {
"093248s0d9f8s9074w490w849e0498403980495": {
  "outputs": {},
  "outcome": "success",
  "conclusion": "success"
},
"checkout": {
  "outputs": {},
  "outcome": "success",
  "conclusion": "success"
},
.... other steps

I made sure all my steps have id fields. What is this first key with the random looking ID?

GitHub Actions assigns a unique identifier to each step in a workflow run. This ID is used internally for tracking and managing the execution of the workflow. It's not meant to be user-friendly or have any specific meaning to you.

I'm so confused, how is this an answer to my question? What is this random ID and what does it mean? It doesn't output a random id key for "each step" in the steps context output just one and I don't know where its coming from. The other steps are shown with their id in the steps context output.

@red888: I am confused at your confusion. This seems like a perfectly sensible answer to the question you have asked; you want to know what the random ID is, and the answer is given in Matt's answer. Could you perhaps clarify your question post if your uncertainty is different to what you've stated?

Is your doubt about whether the random ID is per workflow or per step?

I'm being pretty clear. "GitHub Actions assigns a unique identifier to each step in a workflow run". As I said Im not seeing that. I see only one random ID and the rest of the steps have the IDs that I set. I assigned all my steps IDs. So what is this first one that appears to be randomly generated?
